# Find the difference in C# for two dates

Tags: c#, date, time

I'm trying to create this ATM app for class and my code keeps breaking. It runs fine until I get here and the console shows the "Enter today's date and then breaks immediately.

I'm having trouble with the `DateTime` formatting and I can't find a response that suits what I need for the program. It has to be able to read any date as long as you don't backdate it from the previous date. I'm just trying to get parts of it before I go on but this error doesn't allow me to go any farther.

```
//For Marking First Date
    private void getDate_1()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter today's date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");

        String mydate = Console.ReadLine();
        date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(mydate);
        dateflag = true;

     }

    //For Marking Last Date
    private void getDate_2()
    {
        String date;
        Console.Write("Enter Date: ");
        date = Console.ReadLine();
          date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

       // if (first_date.DayOfYear > last_date.DayOfYear)

        }
```

Comment: Did you try to convert string to date then compare dates?

Comment: " I'm having trouble with the DateTime formatting and I can't find a response that suits what I need for the program." - What formatting? Do you mean parsing? If you're going to specify a format in the prompt, I would suggest using `DateTime.TryParseExact` and specifying the format there, too. It's not really clear whether your problem is *getting* the dates or comparing them...

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParse()` not `Convert.ToDateTime()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent locale settings to have influence on your date parsing, use a specific conversion format. You need [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too:

```
DateTime d;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
{
    Console.WriteLine("An invalid date format was supplied.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getDate_1()
{
    var flag = true;
    while (flag)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter today's date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
       String mydate = Console.ReadLine();
       try 
       {
           date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(mydate);
           dateflag = true;
           flag = false;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Wrong format, try again: ");
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: so would you do the same for    getDate_2()

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `Datetime.Compare` method

something like this

```
 DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
 DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
 int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
```